# A connection attempt failed because the party did not properly respond?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, tcp

I am trying to remotely connect to a Database and every time I try I get the error:

> A connection attempt failed because the party did not properly respond

Comment: More than 700 questions with the _correct_ error message: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22A+connection+attempt+failed+because+the+connected+party+did+not+properly+respond%22+is%3Aq

Answer (score -1):

First thing, Please recheck the connection string: server, database and user used to connect it.

Secondly, make sure user you are using for connection is having sufficient permission over database.

Comment: Correct connetion strings and permissions